# Latex error: sty file not found after pandoc upgrade

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I'm using pandoc to render a markdown document to a pdf.
Everything was working fine when I had pandoc 1.x (I think it was 1.16), which I had installed using `apt-get`. But then I upgraded to version 2.9.2.1 using the [website instructions](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) and now I get the following error when I try to compile my markdown:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.16   \defaultfontfeatures
```

The exact command I'm using in pandoc is this:

```
pandoc input.md \
    -f markdown-implicit_figures \
    -V geometry:a4paper \
    -V geometry:margin=2.5cm \
    -V mainfont="Helvetica" \
    --pdf-engine=xelatex \
    -o output.pdf
```

I googled this problem and found some information saying that this is probably due to that the new pandoc version is not "reading" the `sty` files from the previous version, but I couldn't find clear instructions to fix it. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: the error message says that a sty is not found, not a font. Install unicode-math in your tex system.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to clarify this. My system already has `unicode-math` but pandoc/Latex don't seem to find it for some reason

Comment: check in the log-file (if you can find it, where latex finds the documentclass. Then you know which tex system pandoc is using.

Comment: Clearly not a macOS / MacPorts question, but for the benefit of those MacPorts users who might arrive here after searching for `LaTeX Error: File \`<something>.sty' not found`, particularly after a fresh MacPorts install, try `sudo port install texlive`. Then go make some tea, because it's going to be a while. ([reference](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48971))

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint I was able to fix this error by installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt texlive-latex-recommended install fonts-lmodern lmodern  texlive-latex-extra
```

If that doesn't work then you might use apt-cache search to find a related package:

```
apt-cache search unicode-math
```